# Error when filtering tables of models created in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with lists of models generated in dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

mod.list <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(mod = lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = .))
```

If I plot every model, all works as expected

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

mod.list %>%
  do(.$mod %>% plot)
```

However if I introduce a filter, I get an error

```
mod.list %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 1) %>%
  do(.$mod %>% plot)

Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

I've also tried another type of filter, but the error is the same

```
mod.list %>%
  filter(Species == "setosa") %>%
  do(.$mod %>% plot)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug, you can use

```
mod.list %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 1) %>%
  do(.$mod  %>% (function(x) browser()))
```

Then you see that `class(x)` is a `list`. You want the first (only) element, so

```
mod.list %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 1) %>%
  do(.$mod  %>% `[[`(i=1) %>% plot)
```

Comment: I get 'Error: Anonymous functions must be parenthesized' when running the first code block.  Could you elaborate?